# Child state controller is never executed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was trying to wrap my head around [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) and I've tried to implement the following logic:

- if there is no state, go to state /items
- when processing `/items`, retrieve a list of "items" from the server
- when "items" are received go to state `/items/:item`, where "item" is the first in the list of items, returned by the server
- in state `/items/:item` render a list of items with the corresponding "item" being "highlighted" (the highlighting part is not included in my code)

However, the child state's "controller" function is not executed. I bet it's something really obvious.

Here's the js (I also have it on plunkr with the accompanying templates).

```
angular.module('uiproblem', ['ui.router'])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',
         function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/items');
    $stateProvider
    .state('items', {
        url: '/items',
        resolve: {
            items: function($q, $timeout){
              var deferred = $q.defer();
              $timeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve([5, 3, 6]);
              }, 1000);
              return deferred.promise;
            }
        },
        controller: function($state, items) {
            // We get to this point successfully
            console.log(items);
            if (items.length) {
                // Attempt to transfer to child state
                return $state.go('items.current', {id: items[0]});
            }
        }
    })
    .state('items.current', {
        url: '/:id',
        templateUrl: 'item.html',
        controller: function($scope, items) {
            // This is never reached, but the I can see the partial being
            // loaded.
            console.log(items);
            // I expect "items" to reflect to value, to which the "items"
            // promise resolved during processing of parent state.
            $scope.items = items;
        }
    });
}]);
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/K2uiRKFqe2u5kbtTKTOH

Comment: Your plunker is not complete, there is nothing show at all.

Comment: @Chandermani That's the whole point of the question, kinda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this to your `items` state:

`template: "<ui-view></ui-view>",`

States in UI-Router are hierarchical, and so are their views. As `items.current` is a child of `items`, so is it's template. Therefore, the child template expects to have a parent `ui-view` to load into.

If you prefer to have the child view *replace* the parent view, change the config for `items.current` to the following:

```
{
  url: '/:id',
  views: {
    "@": {
      templateUrl: 'item.html',
      controller: function($scope, items) {
          // ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, this totally worked (both variants). Thanks very much! Doesn't seem very obvious for someone who is quite new to angularjs and to angular-ui, though..